# enable gzip compression for Apache running in docker container

Tags: apache, docker, alpine-linux

I want to enable gzip compression for an application that is served by an Apache instance running inside a Docker container. I'm using the [httpd Alpine image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) as the base image for my Dockerfile.

I followed [this](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/enable-gzip-mod_deflate-compression-apache.html) post, enabled `deflate_module` and appended the shown code to my `httpd.conf` to only compress certain filetypes.

When I restart Apache with `apachectl -k restart` and open the served page, the content does not get gzipped (Content-Encoding Response Header is not set) although `deflate_module` get's loaded (checked with `apachectl -M`).

Am I missing an important step to enable the gzip compression?

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can enable compression using .htaccess

Look at [this](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html). Maybe you can take an idea from there.

Comment: thanks for your response! Unfortunately, the added .htaccess didn't solve the problem :(